# Open Another Existing Excel File -Add data then resave then saveas PDF

Tags: excel, vba

So I Have A VBA project, what i am trying to do is open an Existing file (Pending Data Input) form my userform.  Add data collected from my userform, open add the new data, then save and then saveas PDF.  this is what i have come up with, i do not want to see excel as both excel should be hidden all i want to see is my forms

```
Sub OpenDocument4()
Dim wsh As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
Dim i As Long
Dim lngEndRowInv As Long
Dim FileName1, FileName2 As String
Dim var1
Dim var2
Dim var3
var1 = frmsetup.tbIssuesRear60.Caption
var2 = frmsetup.tbActionsRear60.Caption
var3 = frmsetup.tbOwnerRear60.Caption
Application.Visible = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
FileName2 = "C:\MiltonAuditAppsCenter\SEAT AUDIT\TEMP DOCUMENTS\" & "SEQ-" &           frmsetup.lblsequence.Caption & " " & frmsetup.lbldate.Caption & ".xlsm"
FileName1 = "SEQ-" & frmsetup.lblsequence.Caption & " " & frmsetup.lbldate.Caption & ".pdf"

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName2)
Set wsh = wb.Worksheets("ACTIONS")
Worksheets("ACTIONS").Range("E20").Value = var1
Worksheets("ACTIONS").Range("E22").Value = var2
Worksheets("ACTIONS").Range("J21").Value = var3
Application.Visible = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Sheets(Array("END RESULTS", "DRIVER SEAT", "PASSENGER SEAT", "40% SEAT", "60% SEAT", "RSC SEAT", "ACTIONS")).Select
 ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
     FileName:="H:\APPLICATIONS\SEAT AUDIT\QUERY RESULTS\SEAT AUDIT - PDF\" & FileName1, _
     Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
     IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False,     OpenAfterPublish:=False
End With
wb.Close savechanges:=False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THis looks like it should work, but it might not hurt to get explicit handle on your `Workbook` object, also, since you've already assgined `Worksheets("ACTIONS")` to your `wsh` variable, you should be using that in lieu of hardcoding the `Worksheets("ACTIONS").Range(...).Value` assignments.

```
Sub OpenDocument1()
Dim wsh As Worksheet
Dim wb as Workbook      '## The workbook you want to open
Dim i As Long
Dim lngEndRowInv As Long
Dim FileName As String
Application.Visible = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
FileName = "C:\MiltonAuditAppsCenter\SEAT AUDIT\TEMP DOCUMENTS\" & "SEQ-" & frmsetup.lblsequence.Caption & " " & frmsetup.lbldate.Caption & ".xlsm"
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName)
Set wsh = wb.Worksheets("ACTIONS")
wsh.Range("E20").Value = frmReviewPDFPending.tbIssuesRear60.Text
wsh.Range("E22").Value = frmReviewPDFPending.tbActionsRear60.Text
wsh.Range("J21").Value = frmReviewPDFPending.tbOwnerRear60.Text
wb.Sheets(Array("END RESULTS", "DRIVER SEAT", "PASSENGER SEAT", "40% SEAT", "60% SEAT", "RSC SEAT", "ACTIONS")).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
    "H:\APPLICATIONS\SEAT AUDIT\QUERY RESULTS\SEAT AUDIT - PDF\" & FileName1, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
    False
wb.Close savechanges:=True
Application.Visible = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Note: if you're having trouble with the `ExportAsFixedFormat`, just revert to your original method:

```
 With Sheets(Array("END RESULTS", "DRIVER SEAT", "PASSENGER SEAT", "40% SEAT", "60% SEAT", "RSC SEAT", "ACTIONS")).Select
     ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
         FileName:= "H:\APPLICATIONS\SEAT AUDIT\QUERY RESULTS\SEAT AUDIT - PDF\" & FileName1, _
         Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
         IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= False
 End With
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you can indicate what you've done to debug... which line? What is the error? What is the value you're trying to assign?

Comment: Sorry just rechecking my end to see if i missed something.. when i get the error and debug itops and  highlights the wb.sheets all the way to the false ( so the whole savpdf portion)

Comment: So you're *not* getting any error at `wsh.Range` assignment... what is the error message say?

Comment: object doesn't support this method or property or method, and no it does not stop at wsh, thought it did at first..sorry

Comment: easiest course ofa ction seems to be just to revert that portion of your code to how you originally had it... that of course assumes it was originally working -- and I don't know if it was, because you never really indicated wht the actual problem was with your original code...

Comment: David, thanks for the quick response and help, if i posted the script wrong please let me know, wasn't sure how to do it

Comment: Aside from some possible error in *my* answer code, you still haven't described what *your problem* is in your own code. What's your problem? What isn't working the way you wanted it to work?

Comment: You have fixed it for me, no problems know, just was not sure where to post the finished code, so i posted at the top

Comment: Oh, you don't need to post the finished code :) because that's the purpose of [marking an answer as "accepted"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)